# UnityWebRequest Post Request doesn't work

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine, post

I apologize because I know this question has been asked before but I didn't quite understand the solutions. I'm trying to make a web call from Unity (C#) to PHP to insert data into a MySQL DB. It's successfully making the call but not sending the information. I have the following code implemented:

```
        List<IMultipartFormSection> form = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();

        form.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("namePost", name));
        form.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("stockPost", stock));
        form.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("descriptionPost", description));

        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(postURL, form);

        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.LogError(www.error);
        }

        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Form Upload Completed!");
        }
    }
```

I understand that I need to make the request in this format:

```
formData.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("field1=foo&field2=bar"));
formData.Add(new MultipartFormFileSection("my file data", "myfile.txt"));
```

But I've tried various ways of writing this way with no success. Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Here's my PHP code, i'm new at this.

```
$name = $_POST["namePost"];
$stock = $_POST["stockPost"];
$description = $_POST["descriptionPost"];

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $dbname);
//Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO products (name, stock, description) VALUES ('$name','$stock','$description')";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
$conn->close();
```

**Edit 2:
Edited my C# script but it's still not working  :(**

```
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("namePost", name);
        form.AddField("stockPost", stock);
        form.AddField("descriptionPost", description);

        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(postURL, form))
        {
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
            }
        }
```

Comment: `formData.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("field1=foo&field2=bar"))` - this is incorrect. You're mixing `multipart/form-data` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. When using `multipart/form-data` each form field gets its own multipart section **instead** of URL-encoding it.

Comment: Also, have you verified that your PHP form is able to handle `multipart/form-data` requests in the first place?

Comment: Can you try using `form = new WWWForm();` and then `form.AddField()` to set the form values?

Comment: @Dai I'm not sure I understand how to handle multipart/form-data requests but I haven't had much luck finding more online.

Comment: @OguzOzgul Unity doesn't support this method anymore

Comment: @David yes it does .. see [UnityWebRequest.Post](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html), the only thing obsolete is the usage of the `WWW` class to execute the request

Comment: @David I got this information from the documentation of the latest version (2020.1): https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html

Comment: If you use `.AddField()` for plain text fields and `.AddBinaryData()` for your text file, Unity will post a form with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` and creates a boundary to separate the parts. My recommendation is; use `AddField()` and `AddBinaryData()` and see what is sent using a network analyzer or a stub proxy (like Fiddler), and check your PHP side to handle this (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) request.